# Smallest four-digit palindromic numbers

Tags: mathematics, palindrome

What is the smallest four-digit palindrome that is the sum of two different three-digit palindromic numbers?

There are different answers.

Comment: If the puzzle is not your own creation, you should [include the source](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6404/71652) in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The palindromes:

> 202 + 909 = 1111, 303 + 808 = 1111, 404 + 707 = 1111, 505 + 606 = 1111

The process of getting this answer:

> First, we note that the palindrome we're looking for has 4 digits. Ideally, we'd like something that is less than 2000. So, we'd have first digit and last digit 1. We note that palindromes of length 3 that consist of only the same number (111, 222, ..., 999), when added together, result in a palindrome of the desired form. This leads us to things like 222 + 999 = 1221, 333 + 888 = 1221, 444 + 777 = 1221, and 555 + 666 = 1221. Finally, we note that the "insides" of each of these numbers can be hollowed out (zero'd). This subtracts 110 from each of the above sums, resulting in the smallest 4-digit palindrome with the 2 3-digit palindrome sum property, 1111.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> The smallest sum is **1111 = 505 + 606** (among others, e.g. 202 + 909 also works), and the only other possible sum is 1221 = 555 + 666.

Reasoning:

> Since the sum of two three-digit numbers cannot exceed 2000, the equation should look like $ABA + CDC = 1EE1$. Now we know $A+C \ge 9$ from the highest digit and $A+C$ ends in 1 from the lowest digit, so $A+C=11$. Then the minimum possible sum is **1111** where $B=D=0$, which happens to be a palindrome. One possible sum is $505 + 606 = 1111$. The only other sum that meets the condition is **1221**, where $B+D = 11$.